# PayPal merchant and session destruction

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I wonder if somebody came across with the next situation:
After the payment flow, I click the link "Return to Merchant"

[image]

and I go back to my website but unfortunately my session is destroyed.

Did somebody face an identical situation?

Update: I've made an empty form

[image]

, I mean that it works on its own without any engine's script. And the problem is in existence. 2-3 times out of 10 it works incorrectly. I can't catch a cause. When the problem occurs, the browser doesn't send cookies

[image]

and sends if works

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to simply *not* redirect the user away from your site, and keep it loaded in the background. This gives the best experience, as they are not sent to a possibly-unfamiliar PayPal checkout with no context.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: It seems as I agree, but I'd like to know the cause of the spontaneous absence of cookies.